# No overload for method takes '0' arguments

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

this my action method.

```
public class MainController : Controller
{

    learningEntities1 db = new learningEntities1();
    // GET: /Main/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.GetCustomers());
    }

}
```

this is my stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetCustomers]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@CustomerID int,
@CustomerName varchar,
@PhoneNumber int,
@Address varchar,
@DateofBirth date,
@isActive int
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT * from [dbo].[tblCustomers]
WHERE isActive=1
END
```

I am getting this error on return view. Also tried `@IsActive` and `return View("Index",GetCustomers());`, but the result is the same.

Comment: The exception message seems fairly self explanatory, what parameters does the method `GetCustomers()` take?

Comment: issue is solve when i removed parameters from stored procedure. but at this stage i am only selecting records. will i need these parameters for insert?

Comment: Almost certainly, when inserting records you will need to pass the relevant data to be inserted, since you're using `EntityFramework` have you considered not using stored procedures?

Comment: thanks i got the issue :) yes i also did without using stored procedure. but its easy in stored procedure to put some conditions